# Add a bookmark containing JavaScript, not a URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bookmarks, window.location

I want to have a bookmark on my browser (Firefox 3 or Chrome preferably) that is only a snippet of JavaScript code. It would construct a URL based on the current date and then do a `window.location =`  on that URL.

I know that I could make a page and keep it on my local machine and just refer to it that way, but I was wondering if you could bypass that step and actually have the `location` of the bookmark really just be JavaScript. I could have sworn that this was possible years ago, but I can't find anything that tells me either way now.

Comment: Basics of [bookmarklets](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/javascript-bookmarklet-basics/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding this to your favorites:

```
javascript:(function(){document.location.href="http://stackoverflow.com";})()
```

The correct name for this kind of bookmarks is favelets. For some more inspiration check out this [collection of favelets](http://tantek.com/favelets/).

Comment: The 'correct name'? I've heard 'bookmarklet' used much more frequently than 'favelet'.  To confirm, I looked up [the Wikipedia entry for favelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favelet) and found that it redirects to Bookmarklet and mentions that they represent the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use as your bookmark’s address `javascript:window.location='https://www.google.com/search?q='+Date();`
to create a bookmarklet that searches Google for the current date and time.